# How to browse VPC website in host machine?

Tags: virtualization, sharepoint, virtualhost

I'm kind of confused with the network adapters in Windows Virtual PC, I was able to browse my SharePoint website inside the Virtual PC, but I wanted to browse the website in my host machine,

I wanted to learn these network setting in few different virtual PC (Windows Virtual PC, Hyper V and VirtualBox).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some reading, here are good places to start with:

How does basic networking work in Hyper-V: http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2008/06/16/how-does-basic-networking-work-in-hyper-v.aspx

If you understand this, then the same concept apply to all other virtual technologies